# The formula of quadratic non-linear recurrence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I'm currently working on the recurrence equation $a_{n+1}=a_n^2-a_n+1, a_1=3$, and I wonder if there is a formula for this. It would be better if anyone can give a primary solution.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, *Welcome to the site !*

In fact, what you have is a Sylvester sequence with $a_0=2$.

If you use $a_1=3$, the very first terms are
$$\{3,7,43,1807,3263443\}$$ Have look in $OEIS$ and this is sequence $A000058$ (have a look [here](https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C+7%2C+43%2C+1807%2C3263443&sort=&language=english&go=Search)).

If you have a look at the formula section, you will notice a formula
$$a_n \sim \left\lfloor c^{2^{n+1}}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor \qquad \text{with}\qquad c=1.2640847353053011130795995...$$ $c$ is Vardi's constant (have a look [here](https://oeis.org/A076393) for its decimal representation).

A good rational approximation is $c=\frac{136530}{108007}$ which is error by $5.66\times 10^{-11}$.